# RED Editor in Eclipse-MacOSX - Received FATAL Error that RF framework is not installed in jython

Tags: eclipse, macos, robotframework

Im using Mac OS X and using Eclipse Photon with RED robot editor.

Since it shows below Fatal Error, tried to install robot framework into jython using terminal. But it shows RF is already installed into the system.

Fatal Error in Eclipse:

```
Type FATAL: Python installation /usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/bin has no Robot installed. Fix this problem to build project.
```

Terminal Says:

```
GKs-MacBook-Pro:bin roja$ pip install robotframework
Requirement already satisfied: robotframework in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Please help me in installing robot framework for Jython in Mac. Since i use Eclipse and RobotFramework, I do need this for both python and jython. but system considers the python path in Mac.

Command Executed:

```
GKs-MacBook-Pro:bin roja$ jython -m pip install robotframework

.. contains neither jython-dev.jar nor jython.jar.
Try running this script from the 'bin' directory of an installed Jython 
or setting JYTHON_HOME.
usage: jython [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Try `jython -h' for more information.

GKs-MacBook-Pro:bin roja$ cd
GKs-MacBook-Pro:~ roja$ set JYTHON_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/
GKs-MacBook-Pro:~ roja$ set JYTHON_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/bin
GKs-MacBook-Pro:~ roja$ cd /usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/bin
GKs-MacBook-Pro:bin roja$ jython -m pip install robotframework

.. contains neither jython-dev.jar nor jython.jar.
Try running this script from the 'bin' directory of an installed Jython or setting JYTHON_HOME.
usage: jython [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Try `jython -h' for more information.
```

Comment: What are you entering for the code to appear? What is your RF code? Also was this working before and now suddenly isnt or?

Comment: FATAL error in RED means such error which is critical for RED to work properly - in this case robotframework package in selected interpreter. RED uses RF to validate keywords and libraries which is a basic function of IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Going from bottom to top:
When you issue command pip, it executes the one from /bin which is tied with your default Python -python2.7 from command output. So instead of installing to jython,you are trying to install robotframework to python2.7:

```
GKs-MacBook-Pro:bin roja$ pip install robotframework
Requirement already satisfied: robotframework in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Verify which python interpereter is used with default pip by `pip -V`

In other words,you need to use proper pip which will install packages to proper python interpreter.

First try if you have "pip" under jython path: `ls /usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/bin`

or by running pip as a jython module: `jython -m pip --version`

If so, execute pip from usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/bin or by  `jython -m pip install robotframework`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response!  When changing the directory Mac by itself considers as bin. Please find below the terminal command i used,                                                                                     
 `GKs-MacBook-Pro:~ roja$ cd /usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/bin
                                              GKs-MacBook-Pro:bin roja$ pip install robotframework
  Requirement already satisfied: robotframework in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
GKs-MacBook-Pro:bin roja$ `

Comment: check if pip is within /usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/bin and  try to install it with jython -m pip install robotframework . Depending on jython version/installation process , pip may not be installed to jython by default. My usual go-to is to download get-pip.py from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py  and run it with jython: jython get-pip.py

Comment: The pip file is available but located in /usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/site-packages. Still i tried to execute in bin folder and got different error. I have placed the commands tried under 'Command Executed' section in the question phase. Please check and let me know where Im wrong.

Comment: Not much I can help you with jython installation inssues as I don't have access to MacOS. How did you installed Jython? In our env with RH7, we installed as follows: 1. download installation jar from http://www.jython.org/downloads.html , 2. install: sudo java -jar jython_installer-2.X.X.jar (we used path:  /usr/local/lib/jython) 3. make a link to jython in usr/local/bin:  sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/jython/bin/jython  /usr/local/bin/  , 4.  add jython to PATH: export PATH=/usr/local/lib/jython/bin/jython:$PATH

Comment: for pip (if not installed in package): 1. wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-1.2.1.tar.gz , 2. untar: tar xvfz pip-1.2.1.tar.gz , 3. jython pip-1.2.1/setup.py install

Comment: for robotframework 1. /usr/local/lib/jython/bin/pip install robotframework
2. sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/jython/bin/jybot /usr/local/bin/
verify by: jython -V and: jybot

Comment: Thanks for your dedication.I uninstalled everything and re-installed once again by following your steps. But unfortunately whenever I install robotframework it is sitting in the path /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages.   Do we have any option in RED editor to pull the robotframework from the specified path?

Comment: RED discovers robotframework through interpreters therefore if you select an interpreter,it needs to have robotframework installed.  Are you sure that you installed robotframework using jython? jython -m pip list  - will give you installed jython libs, jython -m pip install robotframework should install it to jython.

Comment: Oops Surprisingly i did redo and followed yours and finally with 'jython -m pip install robotframework'. It worked. Unsure the reason behind it but now it works. Thanks a lot @Jozefow

Comment: Good to hear it! Glad I was helpful.